# Boost asio server program windows port 80 error

Tags: c++, boost, localhost, boost-asio

I am trying to code a program that answers redirected to localhost http requests. That is, my system32/drivers/etc/host file is edited to redirect certain http request to 127.0.0.1 and I hope to answer those with my server program.
I am for now compiling this example :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    argc = 2;
    try
    {
        if (argc < 2)
        {
            std::cerr << "Usage: chat_server <port> [<port> ...]\n";
            system("pause");
            return 1;
        }
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        std::list<chat_server> servers;
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), 80);// std::atoi(argv[i]));
            servers.emplace_back(io_service, endpoint);
        }

        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

the full code can be found here :
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp

I edited the main function to operated on port 80 (http) however i get the following runtime error (exception caught) : 
"a try to access a socket in an unauthorized way has been detected" (note that i translated it from the french error).
If i change the port from 80 to 81, it works. (I can run the client version and send myself messages).
I already tried to run it as admin.
Thanks

Comment: Did you open port 80 in the windows firewall?

Comment: Also make sure the port isn't already taken by another program, [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/) link explains how to do it on windows.

Comment: I did not open this port, did not know I had to, I will check out both those actions and post results, thanks.

Comment: I have opened the port on the windows firewall, always open and in both direction. I still get the same error message.